# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine and Unrecognized database format accdb in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

Note: this is not a duplicate question I tried every possible way that noted here in this site.

in the past I had win 8, access 2013 and Visual studio 2015 and I overcome this problem just by installing Access database engine 2007.

Now I just install win 10, access 2016 and visual studio 2017 and I faced the problem again.

I tried these possible ways:

I installed:
access database engine 2016
access database engine 2010

access run time 2010
access run time 2013
access run time 2016

and the problem is still on

but when I installed access database engine 2007 I ran into this error:

`Unrecognized database format`

then I search for this error and came up with 2 solution:
first that I change my access data base to 2003-2007 format that access didn't let me to do that,

and second to install this:

[Microsoft Office Access Runtime and Data Connectivity 2007 Service Pack 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=27835)

after installing Microsoft Office Access Runtime and Data Connectivity 2007 Service Pack 3 I face whit this error:

`The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot read the data in tFeeds. The minimum required version to read the data is 14.0.0000.0000`

Now what should I do?

Comment: You shouldn’t install multiple.  Just install the version appropriate for you dB version.  Installing ACE 2007 for Access 2016 is just silly

Comment: @MickyD but only 2007 made a change, and I first removed the installed one and then install another version

Comment: If you already had Access installed then there's no reason to install anything else.  What is the target platform for your project?  If 'Any CPU', is the 'Prefer 32-bit' box checked?  Are you installing on 32-bit or 64-bit Windows?  Is the version of Access/ACE you have installed 32-bit or 64-bit?  The usual scenario is 'Any CPU' + 'Prefer 32-bit' + 64-bit Windows + 32-bit Access/ACE.

Comment: @jmcilhinney just by installing access the problem didn't fixed,
I tried any cpu and also 32-bit but didn't work,
64 bit version of windows,

Comment: If your project is targeting 'Any CPU' with Prefer '32-bit' checked and you have 32-bit Access installed on 64-bit Windows then it will work from that perspective and there is no need or point to installing anything else.  If you don't have Access installed then you should installed the Access Database Engine (NOT the Access Run Time) in 32-bit.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Hi, I solved the problem by removing access 2016 and installing access 2013, would you explain it to me how this happened?

Comment: @jmcilhinney historically, installing Access did not also install ACE.  I agree though his problem is more likely that of incorrect x86-x64 bitness

Comment: @MickyD, ACE has only existed since Access 2007, when the ACCDB file format arrived along with DOCX, XLSX and so on. As far as I'm aware, ACE has been part of Access since then as it is the database engine that enables working with ACCDB files.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Agreed, but I seem to remember that I always had to install it on our DEV machines even though we had the appropriate Access version installed already.  Perhaps I missed ticking a box somewhere during install

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Rename the table to something else

2) Then create a table with the original name

3) Copy all fields that were not calculated, as it appears calculated fields are causing your issues.

4) Deploy your new table.

5) Delete Access 2007, and do your work in Access in 2010.

From:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_winother-mso_2013_release/access-2013-database-run-on-version-2007-backwards/16689d2a-291f-48da-bd3d-2c8c473eba5f